# LiveCharts plot XY Value

Tags: c#, data-analysis, livecharts

I'm trying to write a code that plots a list of XY values to Live charts. The list in  question is attached but here is an example:

```
1 0,01
1,01 0,01
1,02 0,01
1,03 0,01
1,04 0,01
1,05 0,01
1,06 0,01
1,07 0,01
1,08 0,01
1,09 0,01
...
2,45 0,15
2,46 0,15
2,47 0,15
2,48 0,16
2,49 0,16
2,5 0,16
2,51 0,17
2,52 0,17
```

I'm using the following code:

```
List<double> xValues, yValues;
            GenerateValues(out xValues, out yValues);
            ChartValues<ObservablePoint> ListPoints = new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>();
            for (int i = 0; i < xValues.Count; i++)
            {
                ListPoints.Add(new ObservablePoint
                {
                    X = xValues[i],
                    Y = yValues[i]
                });
            }

            var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
            brush.Opacity = 0.25;
            var series = new LineSeries();
            series.Values = ListPoints;
            series.Title = "Pressão";
            series.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.OrangeRed);
            series.LineSmoothness = 0;
            series.PointGeometry = null;
            series.Fill = brush;

            var seriesCollection = new SeriesCollection { series };

            if (chart.AxisY[0] != null && chart.AxisY[0].Labels != null)
                chart.AxisY[0].Labels.Clear();
            if (chart.Series != null)
                chart.Series.Clear();
            chart.AxisY[0].Title = "Pressão (bar)";
            chart.AxisX[0].Title = "Tempo (min)";
            chart.Series = seriesCollection;
```

However the result that I'm having doesn't match the X labels on the file. The shape of the curve is correct and the Y values as well but the X value is not. Follow an example of the result: [image: ChartResult]

Can anybody help me to understand this behaviour?

[GitHub with the Application](https://github.com/marcusbianchi/RecipeConfigurationApp)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using your code and some of your values. There's something missing. Post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks I just added in my github account a sample of the application with a sampe file (https://github.com/marcusbianchi/RecipeConfigurationApp)

Comment: I think i misunderstood your question. What exactly are you expecting for the X values. The github example seems to work.